# Retrieve value from hashmap and return

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

How to write code for the following logic in Java-8, here is my code

```
private static Integer getTheInteger() {
    Map<String, Integer> items = new HashMap<>();
    items.put("A", 10);
    items.put("B", 20);
    items.put("C", 30);
    items.put("D", 40);
    items.put("E", 50);
    items.put("F", 60);

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : items.entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getKey().equals("E")) {
            return entry.getValue();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For records, do take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9110949/aruntheimperfect)

Answer (score 4):

You just need a `get` for it ideally. Additionally, to handle a default case(`return 0` here) use [`Map.getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault(java.lang.Object,V)) as in :

```
return items.getOrDefault("E", 0);
```

Comment: This helps you from avoiding to create unnecessary `Optional` or even helps readability as compared to a branching.

Comment: very nice indeed, I seem to forget `getOrDefault` almost every time...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop for that, and you don't need any Java 8 functionality.

```
return items.get("E");
```

Or, to handle the `0` value when key is not in the `Map`:

```
return items.containsKey("E") ? items.get("E") : 0;
```

Comment: I guess I would find [`getOrDefault`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53911413/1746118) better (opinion based), which though under the cover does the same check.

Answer (score 1):

if you were to use a stream for this it would look like:

```
return items.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(s -> "E".equals(s.getKey()))
            .findFirst().map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .orElse(0);
```

but a better approach would be not to iterate over the map entries but instead use `get()` and depending on the result provide a default value.

```
return Optional.ofNullable(items.get("E")).orElse(0);
```